# Air Datepicker inline javascript for enabling date 15 days from newDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using air datepicker for a form element and want to set the calendar to show dates which are 15 days from the current date and disabling selection of all previous dates.

However, I haven't been able to find a solution to this.

The following is the input field code so far:

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-range="true" data-multiple-dates-separator=" - " data-language="en" data-startDate= newDate(+new Date + 12096e5) class="datepicker-here" name="Schedule">
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: In air datepicker have option like "minDate" and "maxDate" using this option you can set date.

Comment: $('#minMaxExample').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    minDate: new Date() // Now can select only dates, which goes after today
})

Comment: for your reference http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/

Answer (score 1):

Using **jQuery UI**

```js
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#date").datepicker({
  defaultDate: "+15",
  changeMonth: true,
  minDate: "+15",
  onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
      instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
      date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, selectedDate, instance.settings);
    dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="date" name="from"/>
```

Using **air Datepicker**

set [minDate](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-24) while initializing datepicker

```js
var dateToday = new Date();
var dates = $("#date").datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  minDate: getMinDate(15)
});

function getMinDate(days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  return date;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js"></script>
<label for="from">From</label> <input type="text" id="date" name="from"/>
```

Comment: This answer uses jQuery UI rather than using Air Datepicker. Nice answer though.

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone added solution for air datepicker as well. check the updated answer.